# How to give text to left and image to right for a button(like dropdown) in swift?

Tags: swift, image, button, dropdown

I am making a dropdown button using storyboard. for that, I need `Select Operator` text in the left and dropdown related image to right. I am using storyboard to make this design. here text and images both are moving like below.

[image]

**but I want like below**

[image]

**for button I have given like below in storyboard**

[image]

please suggest me how to achieve text one side and image another side for a button in swift.

Comment: create a `UIView`, place a label on left and image on right... on top of it place a button with no title and make its width and height equal to `UIView`.

Comment: add ImageView to your View and add constraints on it. Like Trailing to button, center vertically with respect to Button and set width and height of ImageView. It will work perfectly.

Comment: @KeshuR. , thank u, i have the same idea button over the label and image.. but i thought there will be other way.. but i follow this only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set Title Inset and Image inset for like this.

[image: Image and Title Inset]
[image: Here is the output]

Comment: Thank u, i will accept your answer.. but i need text and image very near to edges.. i fallow button over the label and image

Comment: I just gave an example that you can do like this. If you want text and image near edges than you can change value of Right Title Inset and Left Image Inset according to your requirement.